# Angular.js- setTimeout in factory/service to delay event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the client first starts, I am trying to delay the first iteration of the broadcast until the `$watchCollection` in the controller is ready to catch it. However, `setTimeout()` is not solving  the issue and making it where there is no eventlistener at all. Tried this also with `$timeout` and same result. Why is this?

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('sseHandler', function ($rootScope) {
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');
    var sseHandler = {};
    setTimeout(function() {
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function (){
                result = JSON.parse(e.data);
                event = Object.keys(result)[0];
                switch(event) {
                    case "cpuResult":
                        sseHandler.result = result;
                    console.log(sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp);
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
        return sseHandler;
    }, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT**:
I have it in my node server, when a client connects a SSE broadcast is sent to it right away. The Service `source.addEventListener` catches the first broadcast successfully. But the controller is not ready at that time and `$scope.$watchCollection` misses the first broadcast.

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('cpuCtrl',   ['$scope', 'sseHandler', function($scope, sseHandler) {
    var cpuUpdate = function (result) {
        $scope.available = result.cpuResult.avaiable;
        $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
        $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
        $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data
        $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
        $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
    }
    $scope.$watchCollection(function(){
                 return sseHandler.result; 
    }, function(){
        if (sseHandler.result.cpuResult) {
            console.log("yes");
                 cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Yoh can't delay the insrantiation of a service like this. The return value of the timeout callback is just ignored. You should use promises instead...

Comment: how would I wrap a 'once controller is completed/fulfilled' into a promise?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why would you delay setting the property of the service, since the controller can access it whenever they want. You most propably mean that you want to delay the controller's accessing the property until it is set, but shouldn't be necessary (especially if you use a `$watch`). Please, clarify what you are trying to achieve, so we don't hunt down ghosts :)

Comment: Please see Edit in the original message.

Comment: Can't you emit an event "watchcollection ready" or something like that and then broadcast when that event rises? Obviously only once.

Comment: @dman: And the problem is...? What are you trying to achieve with that `$watchCollection` ? Are you hoping that for each change in `sseHandler.result` you will get exactly one call of the $watch callback ? Because that's definitely not the case !

Comment: Problem is- sse broadcasts once every 2 minutes to all clients. When a client connects they get a private broadcast right away...otherwise elements do not populate with data until next broadcast. The code works..except for the issue I just stated.

Comment: @dman: What issue ???

Comment: @ExpertSystem issue is first broadcast is not caught by `$watchCollection`.

Comment: @dman: Did you see my answer below ? Did it solve the problem ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Thanks, but before the last answer was given I ended up placing a `setTimeout()` on the first single SSE broadcast from the webserver, which fixed the issue. This is great learning information though and I will read up on `init()`.

Comment: @dman: OK - just keep in mind that `setTimeout` is not Angular-context aware and timeout-based solutions are often unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want (for whatever reason) that the controller is instantiated and ready to do stuff when `sseHandler` connects to the server, the most reliable approach is to have an `init()` or `connect()` method on `sseHandler` and let the controller call it when it's ready.

E.g.:

```
.factory('sseHandler', function ($rootScope) {
    var sseHandler = {};

    sseHandler.init = function () {
        var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');
        source.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                result = JSON.parse(evt.data);
                event  = Object.keys(result)[0];
                switch (event) {
                    case "cpuResult":
                        sseHandler.result = result;
                        console.log(sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp);
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    };

    return sseHandler;
})

.controller('cpuCtrl', function ($scope, sseHandler) {
    function cpuUpdate(result) {
        $scope.available    = result.cpuResult.avaiable;
        $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
        $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
        $scope.last15     = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data
        $scope.last5      = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
        $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
    }

    $scope.$watchCollection(function () {
        return sseHandler.result;
    }, function () {
        if (sseHandler.result && sseHandler.result.cpuResult) {
            console.log("Yes !");
            cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);
        }
    });

    // Now that everything is set up, let's initialize `sseHandler`
    sseHandler.init();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this way? Factory will return object normally. And after $timeout listener will be set and returned object should be normally populated with data.

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('sseHandler', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');
    var sseHandler = {};
    $timeout(function() {
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function (){
                result = JSON.parse(e.data);
                event = Object.keys(result)[0];
                switch(event) {
                    case "cpuResult":
                        sseHandler.result = result;
                    console.log(sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp);
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
    return sseHandler;
});
```